# How do I construct a reasonable JS implementation of canExecute() for an Experience Editor Button?

Tags: experience-editor, speak, javascript

I am trying to run a field editor for editing some meta data (tagging, description, title, image selection) in Experience editor.

My starting point was https://blog.istern.dk/2015/03/02/running-sitecore-field-editor-from-a-speak-command-in-sitecore-experience-editor/, and it seems mostly functional.

The last thing I need resolved is a proper implementation of the JS method `canExecute()`.

I figured that I would need to look up the templates of the context item, but so far my searches have yielded little of use.

The current JS for my button looks like this

```js
define([
    "sitecore",
    "/-/speak/v1/ExperienceEditor/ExperienceEditor.js"
], function (Sitecore, ExperienceEditor) {

  Sitecore.Commands.LaunchFieldEditor =
  {
    canExecute: function (context) {
      //YOU COULD ADD FUNCTIONALITY HERE TO SEE IF ITEMS HAVE THE CORRECT FIELDS
      return true;
    },
    execute: function (context) {

      //THIS IS THE ACCESSKEY ON LINK TAG "A"
      context.currentContext.argument = context.button.viewModel.$el[0].accessKey;

      ExperienceEditor.PipelinesUtil.generateRequestProcessor("ExperienceEditor.GenerateFieldEditorUrl", function (response) {
        var DialogUrl = response.responseValue.value;
        var dialogFeatures = "dialogHeight: 680px;dialogWidth: 520px;";
        ExperienceEditor.Dialogs.showModalDialog(DialogUrl, '', dialogFeatures, null);
      }).execute(context);

    }
  };
});
```

I have considered rendering the template IDs of the context item into the page content and comparing that to a value stored together with the fields (in accessKey). Such a solution seems a little messy to me, since it would include rendering data into a completely different part of the page.

I have considered doing some sort of service that could resolve the problem based on the field names + the id of the context item, but such a thing would need calling async, and that does not seem acceptable for `canExecute()`.

---

My original script passed field names to the generateRequestProcessor call, by picking them out of the accessKey propery of the rendered button.

I ended up passing the required templates around using the same field and a querystring-like syntax.

This made checking for the required templates fairly simple serverside. Updated script below.

```js
define([
    "sitecore", 
    "/-/speak/v1/ExperienceEditor/ExperienceEditor.js"
], function (sitecore, experienceEditor) {

    sitecore.Commands.LaunchFieldEditor =
    {
        canExecute: function (context) {
            context.currentContext.argument = context.button.viewModel.$el[0].accessKey;
            return context.app.canExecute("ExperienceEditor.CanExecuteFieldEditor", context.currentContext);
    },
        execute: function (context) {

            //THIS IS THE ACCESSKEY ON LINK TAG "A"
            context.currentContext.argument = context.button.viewModel.$el[0].accessKey;

            experienceEditor.PipelinesUtil.generateRequestProcessor("ExperienceEditor.GenerateFieldEditorUrl", function (response) {
                var DialogUrl = response.responseValue.value;
                var dialogFeatures = "dialogHeight: 680px;dialogWidth: 520px;";
                experienceEditor.Dialogs.showModalDialog(DialogUrl, '', dialogFeatures, null);
            }).execute(context);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would have to perform request to the server to check whether your current template meet certain criteria.

**Request class:**

```cs
using Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.Contexts;
using Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.Requests;
using Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.Responses;

namespace Sitecore.Modules.ExperienceEditor
{
    public class CanExecuteMyCommands : PipelineProcessorRequest<ItemContext>
    {
        public override PipelineProcessorResponseValue ProcessRequest()
        {
            var currentItem = RequestContext.Item;
            return new PipelineProcessorResponseValue
            {
                Value = currentItem.TemplateName.Equals("Desired")
            };
        }
    }
}
```

In this case I just check whether `Template name` equals **Desired**. You can apply your own conditions inside that class.

**Configuration:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <sitecore.experienceeditor.speak.requests>
            <request name="ExperienceEditor.YourNamespace.CanExecuteMyCommands" type="Sitecore.Modules.ExperienceEditor.CanExecuteMyCommands, Sitecore.Modules.ExperienceEditor"/>
        </sitecore.experienceeditor.speak.requests>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

**JS call:**

```
canExecute: function (context) {
    return context.app.canExecute("ExperienceEditor.YourNamespace.CanExecuteMyCommands", context.currentContext);
}
```